# CartoDB Runtime Visualization on Local Instance

Tags: carto

I'm trying to create a runtime visualization on a local instance of CartoDB. Here's the relevant code:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, {
            user_name: 'testuser2',
            type:'cartodb',
            tiler_host:'', //??
            tiler_port: '', //??
            tiler_protocol: '', //??
            sublayers: [{
                sql: "SELECT * FROM metro_stop AS pop",
                cartocss: "#pop {marker-fill: #0fb16a; marker-width: 10;}"
            }]
        }, {no_cdn: true}).addTo(map);
```

The problem is, I don't know the values of the three missing parameters: tiler_host, tiler_port, and tiler_protocol. Does anyone know how I would find those out?

Edit to add:
Here's the error I'm receiving when I set tiler_host to 'localhost.lan', tiler_port to '8181', and tiler_protocol to 'http':

http://testuser2.cartodb.com:8181/api/v1/map?config=%7B%22version%22%3A%221.0.0%22%2C%22stat_tag%22%3A%22API%22%2C%22layers%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22cartodb%22%2C%22options%22%3A%7B%22sql%22%3A%22SELECT%20*%20FROM%20metro_stop%20AS%20pop%22%2C%22cartocss%22%3A%22%23pop%20%7Bmarker-fill%3A%20%230fb16a%3B%20marker-width%3A%2010%3B%7D%22%2C%22cartocss_version%22%3A%222.1.0%22%7D%7D%5D%7D&callback=jQuery17209372722392436117_1401785836614&_=1401785836710
Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server.

For whatever reason, this is pointing to CartoDB.com to try to get the info.

Comment: is something running on testuser2.cartodb.com:8181 ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this works, but I found an answer:

Instead of 'tiler_host', I used tiler_domain:'localhost.lan'

(I also used tiler_port:8181 and tiler_protocol: 'http')

I'm not 100% sure why this works, but it does.